# React js constant state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants, state

I have constant array used in react. js. The code is shared below. the change in array when input data changes is not reflecting ui template

```
export const SimplePanel: React.FC<Props> = ({ options, data, width, height }) => {


  const resolutionData = [];

}
```

Comment: You'll need to be more precise. What are you expecting to happen? What is going wrong? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Since you don't seem to store above array in component's state, React does not respond to updating  its contents. If you need to trigger re-rendering on committing changes to this array, you need to leverage `useState()` hook: `const [resolutionData, setRresolutionData] = useState([/*initial value of resolutionData*/])` and do `setResolutionData(/*modified resolutionData array*/)` once you need to update that.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov getting the following error while adding this, Any solution for fixing this

Minified React error #301; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=301 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Comment: @vijesh : I may suspect, you have passed that directly to some event handler (e.g. `onClick={setResolutionData()})` while the proper way is something, like `onClick={() => serResolutionData()}`. The other option, you may be using `setResolutionData` within `useEffect` causing circular state updates and consequent re-renders. But those are only my guesses as I don't see your code :)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov  My function is as follows

   useEffect(() => {
     if (data.series[0].fields) {
       if (data.series[0].fields[0].values.buffer[0].data) {
         showResolutionSLA( data.series[0].fields[0].values.buffer[0].data.responseBody, hoursSelected);
       }
     }
   });

Comment: Inside that Im calling a loop